# Order points on a circle by directional angle

Tags: trigonometry

I have several points on a disk with radius of 150. I want to specify an angle and order the points based on the direction of that angle.

I know the coordinates of each point, and I can find the point on the edge of the circle to define the hypotenuse, but I just can't figure out how to get the distance to the perpendicular line "d"

[image]

After I calculate the distance of each point (light gray line), I can then order the points from least to greatest distance. I hope this makes sense.

[click here to see result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoAXw.png)

Comment: According to the image, your points lie on a **disc**, not on a circle.

Comment: What do you mean by "order the points based on the plane of that angle."? What is the plane of an angle? Is there another plane than the one containing the disc?

Comment: It seems like what you're really asking is for the distance between the bold red line through the origin and the parallel line labeled with "$d,$" rather than some method of ordering points in your circular region/disk. You should probably clarify what exactly it is that you want, and make your title match your question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've edited the question to include the final desired result

Comment: Is this a programming question? If yes, in many languages (e.g. C/C++) there is a function "atan2(y,x)" which returns the angle to the point (x,y), so you could sort points by angle simply by calling this function. There are also some tricks which avoid trigonometry altogether.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean now. A simple solution would be to use the inner product. The inner product of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $x_1x_2+y_1y_2$. If $(x_2,y_2)$ is a vector of length 1, then the inner product is the length of the projection of $(x_1,y_1)$ on $(0,0)-(x_2,y_2)$ (possibly negative if it falls on the other side). So you just have to order them by the inner product with the intersection of the big red line with the circle.

Comment: @Zeno - Yes, this will be used in a C# program but I don't think atan2 describes what I'm looking for.  Also, I don't believe the inner product is it either (or I just don't understand your suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I rotated the points around the origin(0,0) by (360-given angle).  Then the distance to the edge of the disk is the radius (150) minus x.  (r-x).

Comment: Great that you have figured this out. Since you have not understood my suggestion, I would like to remark that this is equivalent to 150 minus the inner product of the chosen point and the appropriate vector. For example, for angle=0 the appropriate vector is (1,0) (and thus you simply return 150-1x-0y = 150-x), for angle=90 the appropriate vector is (0,1) (and thus you return 150-0x-1y=150-y), and so on. In general, the appropriate vector is the vector of length 1 in the direction of the big red line.

Comment: So basically the inner product is the x coordinate after rotation, and the cross product is the y coordinate.